# How to organise student marks according to min value for each subject

Tags: python

I have a file containing 4 student names and their mark for 4 subjects. The first column contains the student name, and the next 5 columns contain that students mark for each subject. Each row is a different student. Using Python, I want to create a list containing the minimum mark for each subject.

For example:

```
Name,Math,Art,Science,English    
Jess,43,87,39,38    
Mark,38,28,87,34    
John,77,36,69,99    
Ash,63,89,97,67
```

Output:

```
[38,28,39,34]
```

I have written this so far in an attempt to create a new list containing the Math marks, which I was then going to sort..

```
csvfile = "sample.csv"

file = open(csvfile,"r")

math = []
for line in file:
    math.append(f[1])
```

However, it is returning the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ...
    mark1.append(f[2])
TypeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object is not subscriptable
```

What am I doing wrong in order to create a new list containing the score on index 1 for each line? Thank you

Comment: What have you tried? Please post your code.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! We are here to help you solve any errors in your code, but we are not here to help you write code for free. Edit your post with what you have tried and what errors you faced and we might be able to help you.

Comment: Please repeat the intro tour, especially [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  Stack Overflow is not a general tutorial resource.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the feedback :) I have edited my post to focus on a specific coding issue

Answer (score 0):

Using CSV Reader (great for parsing CSV files)

[Reference](https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse140/13wi/csv-parsing.html)

**Code**

*Updated with suggestion from @JustinEzequiel (see comments)*

```
import csv

#https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse140/13wi/csv-parsing.html
with open('sample.csv', mode='r') as infile:
    # Place students as a list of dictionaries
    reader = csv.DictReader(infile, skipinitialspace = True)

    # Get subjects from header (fieldnames)
    subjects = reader.fieldnames[:]  
    subjects.remove('Name')

    #  Get students names and grades
    lst = [student for student in reader]

    # Find min by subject for all students
    min_scores = [min(student[subject] for student in lst) for subject in subjects]

    print(min_scores)
```

**Test**

*File sample.csv*

```
Name,Math,Art,Science,English
Jess,43,87,39,38
Mark,38,28,87,34
John,77,36,69,99
Ash,63,89,97,67
```

*Output*

```
['38', '28', '39', '34']
```

Comment: You don't need the line `header = next(infile).strip().split(',')` when using a DictReader. See https://repl.it/repls/TurboCrowdedCharacterencoding

Comment: @JustinEzequiel--I know it reads the header into the dictionaries, but I wanted the header separated so I could get the name of the subjects to loop over.  Do you have another suggestion for getting the subjects?